# ExtJS can't select month/year in datepicker

Tags: extjs, datefield

I'm using ExtJS 3 and when I want to select a date for the datepicker, I can only set day and month (through left/right arrows). The month/year panel comes down but quickly goes away, making it impossible to select it. This is a desktop recording that describes best the behaviour: http://flic.kr/p/9VbX3m . Also, I am mentioning that I don't get any errors in Firebug.

**Update**: I noticed that the month/year box that drops down remains down and I can bring it up by changing the `top:0;` property to something like `top:-180px;` and then I can select the month/year, but why ? I didn't mess with any CSS values.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ext? 3.3 or 3.4? I would try updating to 3.4 if you haven't done so already, has some CSS fixes

Comment: I got 3.3. Can I raw update the ExtJS version ? To replace the whole folder and modify header scripts accordingly ? Is 3.3 code 100% compatible with 3.4 ? Thanks for the interest.

Comment: yeah, you should have no problems updating... I did it recently and had no issues (the app is heavily modified too). I think its nearly all CSS fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, too bad I did not concentrate on the CSS part of my application sooner. I am using the GridFilters extenstion and it comes with GridFilters.css file. In my version, line number 46->48 which is this:

```
li.x-menu-list-item div {
    display: inline;
}
```

got me in trouble, overriding the month/year menu's position. Really thought that it's one of my JS scripts that is causing this because it has been working for months like this and suddently the month/year chooser stopped working.

It's all good now, I've commented out those lines and gridfilters are also working/displaying as it should.

Thanks for the interest.